# Barcode scanner reads input into text file, then selects all text and deletes it

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

I am trying to set up a (USB) Motorola Symbol DS6708 barcode scanner to scan QR code encoded with some contact information onto a text file.

When scanning in a barcode, the expected text is displayed on in the text file. When it is finished reading it in all the text is selected and deleted.

If it hit ctr+z, the text is undeleted and displayed in the file.

The desired result is in this format:

Name
Title
Company
Phone
ect

I'm not really sure where to start with debugging this. I am assuming that there is some characters being read in at the end that doing the equivalent of ctrl+a and delete.

**EDIT**
I tried scanning using the 123Scan2 from Motorolo, and this was the result:

```
 <STX> <STX> <STX>318315647 <ETX> <LF>NAME<ETX>  <ETX>LNAME<ETX> <LF>TITLE <ETX>
 <LF>COMPANY <ETX> 
 <LF>ADDRESS <ETX> <LF>ADDRESS <ETX> <LF>CITY<ETX>,  <ETX>ST<ETX>  <ETX>12345<ETX> <LF>USA <ETX> 
 <LF>PHONE    <ETX> <LF>PHONE     <ETX> 
 <LF>EMAIL <ETX> <LF> <LF> <LF> <LF> <LF> <SUB> <CR>
```

**EDIT**

I attempted to set console application with C# and read in the input with Console.Read() or Console.ReadLine(), but the input actually caused the application to stop running, and then the input text was written into the text of the Program.cs file on Visual Studio.

The simple console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("start");

        int result;
        while ((result = Console.Read()) != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", result, (char)result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not really sure where to start with debugging this. I am assuming
>   that there is some characters being read in at the end that doing the
>   equivalent of ctrl+a and delete.
>
> I attempted to set console application with C# and read in the input
>   with Console.Read() or Console.ReadLine(), but the input actually
>   caused the application to stop running, and then the input text was
>   written into the text of the class on Visual Studio.

I would bet that the data contain an [EOF char (Ctrl+Z)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_File). All [text devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_file) (like console I/O) use this as an end signal, and it is still supported in modern OSes, although little known these days. And of course it is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx).

> When it is finished reading it in all the text is selected and
>   deleted. If it hit ctr+z, the text is undeleted and displayed in the
>   file.

You probably want to say, that the text is shown in the editor, and selected/deleted from the editor. A file can't hardly display anything on it's own, it just contains something. By the way, the fact that EOF is Ctrl+Z and your editor's undo is also Ctrl+Z is pure coincidence.

As you don't show any code, it's hard to say anything about it. I'd probably do a Read() loop and store everything useful I get in a suitable place, for example in a file :-) This data are then to be processed in a second step.

PS: [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284082/console-in-peek-returns-1-on-enter) may also be helpful.

Comment: "the text is shown in the editor, and selected/deleted from the editor." Yes that is what I mean. I am looking into the EOF char now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't played with barcode scanners for a while but this sounds to me that either the barcode you are scanning contains the control codes to do Ctrl-A and Del or that the scanner is programmed in that way.

To the host PC a barcode scanner basically appears like a keyboard. If you can type it, the barcode scanner can deliver it, including all Ctrl / Shift / Alt shortcuts.

If you have the scanner from new you should have a sheet of barcodes that allow you to program it up and affect its behavior.  Have a look for a full reset barcode and see if that improves things.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am assuming is going on. [I have the manual]( ]http://www.motorolasolutions.com/web/Business/Products/Bar%20Code%20Scanning/Bar%20Code%20Scanners/General%20Purpose%20Scanners/_Documents/static_file/ds6708.pdf) and was trying to scan some of the reset commands but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try their sdk [downloaded here](http://support.symbol.com/support/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=13517&sliceId=&dialogID=568290721&stateId=1%200%20568278842). tell me if it still deletes the file in the textbox of the form.

If it isn't deleted, it might be better to add an export to a text file button.