# Console.KeyAvailable is true, but Console.In.Peek() stalls

Tags: c#, stream

I'm making the game Snake.  It's all working but if you press buttons too quickly it has an unfortunate behavior.  Before I started attacking this issue, the code handled a single key press per loop iteration, and if you pressed a key multiple times in a row, it took that many loops before you could change direction.

My initial change was to read all the keys that have been pressed since the last game loop, and only apply the last one.  This worked, but really, if I press two keys, I want them both to be applied.  What I don't want is for me to be stuck going right because I pressed right three times.

So my next approach was to peek at the next inputted character and see if it's the same as the last one.  If so, read it out of the stream, and try again.

My understanding is that `Console.KeyAvailable` returns `true` if there is any unread data in the input stream, and `Console.In.Peek()` returns the first character of data in the input stream, or else hangs until there is data there.

Here's my current code:

```
private static void UpdateDirection()
{
    ConsoleKey key = ConsoleKey.Escape; // dummy key

    Dir curDir = s_snakeDir;
    lock (s_consoleLock)
    {
        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

            // ignore multiple key presses of the same direction
            while (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                int next = Console.In.Peek();
                if (next != (int)key)
                {
                    break;
                }

                // read and ignore next character
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }

        switch (key)
        {
            // do stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

If I press two keys on the same loop, the game stalls.  What happens (as far as I can tell) is it gets to `int next = Console.In.Peek();` and waits for the next character.

What I don't understand is why `Console.In.Peek()` needs to wait.  If `Console.KeyAvailable` is true, then there should be a character in `Console.In`'s stream.

### EDIT

I believe I've figured out the issue.  `Console.In.Peek()` is looking for characters, not key presses, and the arrow buttons don't have characters associated with them.  So my next question is how to do what I want to do.

Comment: have you tried doing a google search..also check here for and example on how to construct your while loop http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284082/console-in-peek-returns-1-on-enter

Comment: I have, actually, and I came across that link several times.  It does not help with arrow keys for the same reason I'm having issues.  Further, `Console.In.Read()` will take the data out of the stream, which is something I don't want to do, because I want the keys to be available for the next game loop.

Comment: how are you storing the Keys for the next game loop then.. if I am understanding you correctly..?

Comment: They're "being stored" in the stream.  I use `Peek()` to take a look but not to read, which will pull it out of the stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also made a snake multiplayer game (source code [here](https://github.com/xKippi/Snake)) and i had **exact** the same poblem: 
If somebody presses a key for a while then the direction is set very delayed...

I solved this problem with a keyBuffer and a keyCheck thread:

```
List<ConsoleKeyInfo> keyBuffer = new List<ConsoleKeyInfo>();

new Thread(() =>
{
    while(true)
    {
        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (keyBuffer.Count > 0)
            {
                if (keyBuffer[keyBuffer.Count - 1] != key)
                    keyBuffer.Add(key);
            }
            else
                keyBuffer.Add(key);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}).Start();

while(true)
{
    if (keyBuffer.Count>0)
    {
        switch (keyBuffer[0].Key)
        {
            //SwitchSomeStuff
        }
        keyBuffer.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    //PlayGame
}
```

Comment: I advise the usage of `ConcurrentQueue<T>` and `Task<T>` instead of `List<T>` and `Thread`.

Comment: @unknown6656 The List<T> is not thread-safe but you could use a lock. I don't understand why you shouldn't use Thread.

Answer (score 4):

There's no conceivable point in not using Console.ReadKey().  You are only interested in the position of the keys to control the snake, not what letter they produce.  WASD is ZQSD in France for example:

[image: french keyboard layout]

And you get a use out of the cursor keys, you can't do that with Console.Read()

Comment: So what is your solution, or do you have one?  I've considered using a queue, where I read all the keys that have been pressed, remove consecutive duplicates, and store each keystroke in the queue to be processed on the next loop if the queue is not empty.

Comment: No idea what the point of that might be.  Just update "curDir" based on the key you read.